# Sorting the imported data WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, struct

Hi i have problem with sorting data. I'm reading from datafile into structure. I would like to sort as follows:

my input data:

Name    Surname     age     gender

Jan     Kowalski    45      m

Adam    Kowalski    44      m

Anna    Nowak       44      k

Andrzej Piłka       22      m

Danuta  Drzewo      25      k

Ola     Nowak       25      k

Jan     Piłka       66      m

Jan     Kowalski    45      m

Adam    Kowalski    44      m

Stan    Drzewo      66      m

i expect:

File 1

Jan     Kowalski    45  m

Adam    Kowalski    44  m

Jan     Kowalski    45  m

Adam    Kowalski    44  m

File 2

Andrzej Piłka       22  m

Jan     Piłka       66  m

File 3

Anna    Nowak       44  k

Ola     Nowak       25  k

File 4

Danuta  Drzewo      25  k

Stan    Drzewo      66  m

Then I would like to work on the data, draw a graph of how old the Kowalskis are.
The data that I will be loading is of different size, once Kowalski is 10 times 100. However, the number of columns is constant.

I can sort in such a way as to get:

LP  Surname

4   Kowalski

2   Piłka

2   Nowak

2   Drzewo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an adapter to convert from your data to a class Person with attributes Age, Name, Gender, Surname and then use Linq to sort. We can't help you however if you don't specify how you import the data.